# Connect to Google Drive with Named Credential

Tags: integration, google-drive

I have integration with google drive using Named Credential. But sometimes, unexpectedly, the connection with Google Drive disappears (browser doesn`t logout of Google accounts). It happens randomly (once at week/ or two weeks).
Then I open Named Credential and 'edit' them (I don't change anything), then 'save' and reselect the Google account I want to connect to. And then everything works correctly.

Why does this happen? How to fix it?
[image]